# Anime with a scene in which an old lady transfers a ball of energy from herself to the younger, male main character

Tags: story-identification, anime

Ok, so I saw this at some point years ago (probably close to 10 years ago, if not a little more), and it's been stuck in my head. I keep thinking *Naruto*, but haven't found it.

So the scene I recall involves the main character (young male, conservative haircut, not wild like Goku's) and an old lady who is either a witch or some kind of teacher to him (I keep picturing [Baba](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Fortuneteller_Baba) from *Dragon Ball Z*). They're in a cave, and she tells him she will give him her energy, or ki, or power, but it could be too strong and may kill him. She passes him a glowing ball that emerges from her chest, and he absorbs it into his chest, falling onto the ground in pain and screaming.

After a few moments, it seems he may not be able to pull through, so she says something like "I was afraid of this" and starts to pull the ball back out of him. But he suddenly yells "NO! I can do this!" or something to that effect and reabsorbs the ball, this time able to overcome and absorb it fully, resulting in a huge power boost for him. After this, I'm fairly sure she died.

That's all I can recall, and it's really, really bothering me. Thank you for any help!

The art style was older; it looked maybe mid-90s or early 2000s, from what I can recall. I seem to remember the old lady being dressed more formally like a Supreme Kai, while the main character seemed to be in just jeans and a sleeveless shirt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you be a bit more precise about roughly far back you are likely to have watched this?

Comment: Let's see, it's been probably close to 10 years if not a little more. I know it's gotta be a popular anime I just cannot for the life of me figure out what to search for

Comment: Do you remember how old the main character is roughly; e.g. adult, young adult, teen? Or, other things than the story, like the art style, where you watched it (country and media/platform), or perhaps even the opening/ending theme? Feel free to [edit] and update your question directly.

Comment: See if something here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BequeathedPower or here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnergyDonation

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be this scene in Episode 44 of *[YuYu Hakusho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuYu_Hakusho#Anime)* (aka *Ghost Files*, *Poltergeist Report*, or *Ghost Fighter*) (1992–1994)?

> [Genkai](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/Genkai) tells [Yusuke](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/Yusuke) his final test is to kill her. Yusuke has second thoughts. He meets Genkai in a cave and says he can't do it. She tells him that was the first part of the test and that she would not give her power to someone who would kill her. She reveals her source of power is her Spirit Wave Orb and takes out a bright ball of energy. Yusuke's test is to absorb it. He agrees to the terms, though the test could kill him. She puts it in him. He feels nothing at first, but then he collapses from the pain.

- [Episode 44, YuYu Hakusho Wiki](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_44)

Relevant dialogue (English dub):

> **Genkai:** It's too much. Your body can not take any more. I'm removing the Spirit Wave Orb before you're just a lump on the floor. Come on. Ah...
>
> **Yusuke:** Hey… Hey! Give that back, you old bitch!
>
> **Genkai:** Don't be an idiot, Yusuke. Making you absorb this energy so early was a gamble, and now we see why. All my training with you will be a waste of time if you're not even alive to fight against Toguro. Perhaps there's still time to put it off.
>
> **Yusuke:** Shove it up your ass! You're not my freakin' mother, so don't try telling me what's good for me!

Your description of the main character matches [Yusuke Urameshi](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/Yusuke_Urameshi), the protagonist of *YuYu Hakusho*, and your description of the old lady matches [Genkai](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/Genkai).

Comment: THATS IT!!!! HOLY CRAP   thank you. This has floated around my brain for literal years.